# My validator is not in 'solana validtors'

Tags: validator, stake

I ran a node on mainnet, following the docs at https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/setup-a-validator.

Node is running, vote account was created.
Node indentity H6JQDBHenNx2HAiJvFPAPhuqt8v4oT9mAXk6ShFrs9DG, vote account CHi1pXRe1VBTFspeRn3qrjtaAnuExAuBA9u6kZi7Fxre can be searched at explorer "https://solscan.io/".

But I cant find my node identify in list of 'solana validator' command's result, wallets like Phantom can't find my validator neither, therefor can't stake any sol to my node.

- solana validators -um | egrep 'H6JQDBHenNx2HAiJvFPAPhuqt8v4oT9mAXk6ShFrs9DG|CHi1pXRe1VBTFspeRn3qrjtaAnuExAuBA9u6kZi7Fxre'

got nothing

- solana catchup H6JQDBHenNx2HAiJvFPAPhuqt8v4oT9mAXk6ShFrs9DG -um

Error: error sending request for url (https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/): connection closed before message completed.

- ping api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

PING api.mainnet-beta.solana.com (199.254.199.54) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 199.254.199.54 (199.254.199.54): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=82.2 ms
64 bytes from 199.254.199.54 (199.254.199.54): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=82.1 ms

But 'solana gossip' command found my node:
solana gossip | grep 'H6JQDBHenNx2HAiJvFPAPhuqt8v4oT9mAXk6ShFrs9DG'

210.209.69.58   | H6JQDBHenNx2HAiJvFPAPhuqt8v4oT9mAXk6ShFrs9DG | 9000   | 9003  | 210.209.69.58:8899    | 1.18.3  | 3352961542

Do you, my lovely guys have encounted this issue and know how to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the implementation of `get_vote_accounts`, which is used by `solana validators`, it looks like all vote accounts with no stake are skipped: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/aba8ce5f3ef5af4c7241906ccf419e0dd4d7ff69/runtime/src/epoch_stakes.rs#L95

Since your vote account was just created, and no stakers have delegated, your node won't pass the given filter. Once you get some stake, it should show up.